# Extjs combobox treepanel list coming transaparent

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I am new to extjs. I have created extjs 6.0.2 app using cmd. everything is working fine but my combobox list and treepanel list are coming as transparent without any style.

[image: combobox]

[image: treepanel]

Comment: Check the classes on those elements. What are they? If so, are they having styles applied? You haven't provided enough information.

Comment: Let Cmd compile your project once, maybe that will fix the issue in the uncompiled version also.

Comment: @Alexander I am sorry. How do i compile my code? I am using sencha app build to build my project.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, build your project once. CSS is only updated when you build the project, and if your project didn't contain that component during the last time you built it, the CSS for that component is missing from the style sheet.

Comment: @Alexander i deleted the build folder and rebuilt it..Still no change..:(

Comment: Does it look the same in other browsers?